# Optional element in regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this pattern:

```
"^([\\d.]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(.+?)\" (\\d{3}) (\\d+|\\S+)"
```

That I use it on the following apache access log entry:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jul/2011:20:29:14 +0100] "GET /TestWebPages/MScAIS-SEWN-Search-Optimisation.html HTTP/1.1" 200 5569
```

Sometime after the 7th element I might or might not have something. E.g.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jul/2011:20:29:14 +0100] "GET /TestWebPages/MScAIS-SEWN-Search-Optimisation.html HTTP/1.1" 200 5569 –
```

Sometimes I have the `-` at the end and sometime it just doesn’t exists.

How can add this to my pattern? I tried using `(\\S{0})` but it did not work!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding: `(\\s–){0,1}` which means you could have zero or one occurrence of " –"

Answer (score 0):

Try the question mark:

```
\S? (alternative \S{0,1})
```

or for multiple occurence the asterisk:

```
\S* (alternative \S{0,})
```